# Command line argument not stored (using boost)

Tags: c++, boost, command-line-arguments, boost-program-options

I want to store a command line value into a variable. Here's my complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int nselect = 100;
  boost::program_options::options_description desc("Allowed options");
  desc.add_options()
        ("help,h", "print usage message")
        ("nselect,N", boost::program_options::value<int>(&nselect), "number to select");
  boost::program_options::variables_map vm;
  boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);

  if (vm.count("help")) {
      std::cout << desc << "\n";
      return 0;
  }
  std::cout<<"nselect = "<<nselect<<"\n";
  return(0);
}
```

I compile it as `g++ a.cpp -lboost_program_options`, and then run:

```
$ ./a.out -N 5
nselect = 100
```

Why isn't it storing the command line value?

**Resolution**:

Calling `notify(vm)` automatically stores the value into the variable specified in the variable. Or one can map it from vm, as in the answer by @Matthieu-Brucher below.

Comment: So, is this a bug in boost::program_options that this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually do something different, more idiomatic for ProgramOptions:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;

po::options_description desc("Options");
desc.add_options()
    ("help,h", "print usage message")
    ("nselect,N", po::value<int>()->default_value(100), "number to select");

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
po::notify(vm);

int nselect = vm["nselect"].as<int>();
```

I didn't the `notify` call in your code, that may be the only thing to change, although I would go for the idiomatic way instead for readability.

Comment: Thanks! This can work. It's just that I would have to go over the list of all arguments first in the description and then in the vm. If I change one I have to change the other. It'd be nice to be ale to use the value() function too.

Comment: Well, as it's stored in `vm`, you don't need to have a list of arguments somewhere else. I only have `nselect` in one place.

Comment: Actually, notify(vm) is what was missing in my code. It works after adding it.

Comment: That was my thought as well. But still not very idiomatic, hence the suggestion. All the tutorials I've seen use this.

Comment: True, or a mixture of the two as in https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/program_options/example/options_description.cpp